# How to get Session CUSTOMER ID outside Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, header, customer-session

Hereby, I working in  PHP  Outside Magento Folder.Here I need to get Session values like Customer ID into Outside Magento.Here I working this sample code in outside Magento.

```
<?php
// Your Magento Mage.php
// Mage Enabler WordPress plugin users may
// skip line numbers 5, 6 and 7
require_once ("/var/www/magento_pack/app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");
#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default');
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

//get the loaded head and header blocks and output
$headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
$footerBlock = $layout->getBlock('footer');
// echo $headBlock->toHtml() . $headerBlock->toHtml().$footerBlock->toHtml();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
  echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
else
  echo 'Not logged in';
  exit;
```

But Doesnt show proper customers details.How to achieve outside magento session value exactly customer details.Kindly Advise me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try moving your core session initialization above the layout calls:

```
require_once ("/var/www/magento_pack/app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");
#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default');
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

//get the loaded head and header blocks and output
$headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
$footerBlock = $layout->getBlock('footer');
// echo $headBlock->toHtml() . $headerBlock->toHtml().$footerBlock->toHtml();
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
  echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
else
  echo 'Not logged in';
exit;
```

Comment: Hi @Laura..I have already this above code in my sample Script.Kindly go through it..Eagerly wait for your  valuable answer..

Comment: Did you move the session call up and it's still not working?

Comment: Yes @Laura..Still not working fine.I tried many ways to reach it but yet not get back proper result.Kindly advise me..

Comment: I updated the code block in the answer. This is working for me. One question: are you sure the user is actually logged into the frontend of the Magento site when you're running this?

Comment: Yes @Laura..absolutely correct..i need to get user detail outside magento. I have connect with core php website i need to merge log-in credential.Let me check it out and get back to you..

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any need to do all this, something like:

```
require 'Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()
```

should do the job.

This only works, if you are calling this script under the same domain (read as: cookie domain) as your real magento. If you can't read the session id from the cookie, because you are under another domain, you are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<?php
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
// Define the path to the root of Magento installation.
define('ROOT', Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "Customer is logged in";}
else{
    echo "Customer is not logged in";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';


umask(0);

Mage::app('default');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) {
  echo $customerId = $sessionCustomer->getId();
} else {
   echo "Not Logged";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$cusData = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$customerId = $cusData->getCustomer()->getid();
```